# I am facing an error when installing my Django env it is saying "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Tags: javascript

After pipenv install djanko==2.1
I am facing an error saying "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

I did pipenv install djanko==2.1 and was expecting to create a virtual environment

Comment: How is this problem related to Javascript? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Should it be `djanko` or `django`?